# Stop fancy box 3 opening when iframe URL fails to load

Tags: fancybox-3

I'd like to be able to redirect to a given URL if it fails to load with Fancybox 3. The users supply the URL's so it could be a youtube video, image, or some other arbitrary link. In the case of something like a Google Doc, google prevents you from loading those inside iframes, so I'd like to catch that error and stop the fancy box viewer from loading at all and instead redirect to that URL directly in the browser. I can kind of get it working but I can't seem to stop the fancy box dialog from showing before the redirect happens:

```
$.fancybox.defaults.afterLoad = (instance, current) ->
  if current.hasError
    window.location = current.src
    instance.close()
```

I've tried returning false.

Comment: Not sure that’s really easily possible … It has to create the iframe (and presumably add it to the DOM as well), before it can even determine that the content could not be loaded into it - and I doubt that it does that in an “invisible” fashion first, on the off chance that it might go wrong. _“I've tried returning false.”_ - I don’t think any of the events it provides are actually cancel-able. But if you redirect inside the current window, the user should only be seeing this viewer for a short moment anyway, right?

Comment: You're right in that it's not possible to look into the results of a cross domain iframe request. I managed to work around it by doing a light-weight HEAD request on the URL first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @misorude mentions, there isn't a way to detect if the iframe failed to load for cross site requests. In the end I decided to do away with previewing off-site links completely and do a redirect like so:

```
$.fancybox.defaults.afterLoad = (instance, slide) ->
  if !slide.redirecting && slide.contentType == 'html'
    slide.redirecting = true
    message = """<div class="fancybox-error"><p>Redirecting...</p></div>"""
    instance.setContent slide, message
    window.location = slide.src
```

This displays a nice redirecting message and then sends the user on to that link via the browser. `contentType` is only `html` when it's not `image`, `video`, `map` etc... from the other media type plugins. This means fancybox can still show youtube links without trouble even though these are iframe and html based.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I have come up with so far:

```
$.fancybox.defaults.defaultType = 'iframe'
$.fancybox.defaults.beforeLoad = (instance, current) ->
  $.ajax
    url: current.src
    method: 'HEAD'
  .catch ->
    window.location = current.src
    instance.close()
```

The default for a URL is `ajax` if it fails all the other tests (like image and video), so we need to switch this to iframe first. Then I do an ajax HEAD call to see if the result is successful, if not, we can just redirect to the src. `instance.close()` is the best way I could find to stop the fancybox from loading (it could already be loaded if this is a slideshow/gallery anyway). There is a brief flash before the page then redirects to the URL.

Comment: That HEAD request would only work for resources that are CORS-enabled though - which isn’t the same thing as whether a page allows being display in foreign frames. I think this has a lot of potential to produce false positives.

Comment: That's true. It also catches youtube URL's before they're re-interpreted and changed to a video embed. I'll keep thinking. I've seen someone say to make the request on the server first to see what the headers are.